# A group of constants in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want something like this:

```
class Fruits:
   APPLE = 'APPLE'
   ORANGE = 'ORANGE'
   MANGO = 'MANGO'

# I want to access members easily
print(Fruits.APPLE)

# I want to list all members
print(list(Fruits))

# I want to check if a string belongs to the set
print('POTATO' in Fruits)
```

I want plain string constants, grouped into a class with:

- member check
- listing all values

**Python enums do not seem to be suitable**, because:

- Enums are not plain strings, introduce a new type
- Enums require using `.value`
- Not directly serializable and are otherwise clumsy.

Is this implementable in Python? I suppose I might need some magic methods or metaclasses for this?

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it, as you mention, with a metaclass.

Comment: @qouify Cool! Please share one if you have the code. I wonder how complex that is,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement yourself you can do so with a `metaclass` and an `__iter__` method.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # this just iterates through the class dict and removes
        # all the dunder methods
        cls.members = [v for k, v in dct.items() if not k.startswith('__') and not callable(v)]
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
    
    # giving your class an __iter__ method gives you membership checking
    # and the ability to easily convert to another iterable
    def __iter__(cls):
        yield from cls.members

class Fruits(metaclass=Meta):
    APPLE = 'APPLE'
    ORANGE = 'ORANGE'
    MANGO = 'MANGO'


print(Fruits.APPLE)
print('APPLE' in Fruits)
print(list(Fruits))
```

Comment: just ```yield from cls.members``` in __iter__

Comment: Theres a logic error, your `cls.members` holds the `key` instead of the `value` from `__dict__`. See corrected [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/PolishedWigglyWaterfall#main.py)

Comment: That's a misunderstanding on my part. I assumed OP wanted the member names and not the values because of this comment. `# I want to list all members`

Answer (score 3):

You want Python "[enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)":

```
In [7]: from enum import Enum                                                                    

In [8]: class Fruits(Enum): 
   ...:    APPLE = 'APPLE' 
   ...:    ORANGE = 'ORANGE' 
   ...:    MANGO = 'MANGO' 
   ...:                                                                                          

In [9]: print (Fruits.APPLE)                                                                     
Fruits.APPLE

In [10]: list(Fruits)                                                                            
Out[10]: [<Fruits.APPLE: 'APPLE'>, <Fruits.ORANGE: 'ORANGE'>, <Fruits.MANGO: 'MANGO'>]
```

For containment checking, though, you can't use the string directly -
evaluating `"APPLE" in Fruits` directly would raise a TypeError, but this is possible:

```
In [18]: "APPLE" in Fruits.__members__                                                           
Out[18]: True

# or:
In [15]: Fruits("APPLE")                                                                         
Out[15]: <Fruits.APPLE: 'APPLE'>
```

And, as for the part of your questions that goes:

> Is this implementable in Python? I suppose I might need some magic
> methods or metaclasses for this?

Yes, it is. And yes, it needs both - but it was all done back by Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

A very basic solution with a meta-class:

```
class EnumClass(type):

    def __iter__(cls):
        for key in cls.__dict__:
            if not key.startswith('__'):
                yield cls.__dict__[key]

    def __contains__(cls, item):
        return item in cls.__dict__ and not item.startswith('__')


class Fruits(metaclass=EnumClass): 
    APPLE = 'APPLE'
    ORANGE = 'ORANGE'
    MANGO = 'MANGO'

# I want to access members easily
print(Fruits.APPLE)

# I want to list all members
print(list(Fruits))

# I want to check if a string belongs to the set
print('POTATO' in Fruits)
print('APPLE' in Fruits)
```

It's very simplistic and has flaws (e.g., you cannot add methods in Fruits) but it's ok for the use cases you mention.